# copyobj legend and facealpha issue when setting log yscale

Tags: matlab, legend, figure

I have the following code for drawing a picture:

```
%scamp data
[flipedBV, flipeddepth] = flipit(depthi, BVsurf_int_ens);

i=linspace(0,5,100);
edges_eps=10.^(-i); 
logedg_BV= log10(fliplr(edges_eps)); 

[n_BV,xout_BV] = histc(histazza(log10(flipedBV)), logedg_BV);

x = logedg_BV;

%model data
[n_BVn,xout_BVn] = histc(histazza(log10(sqrt(-BVsurf_Num_ens))), logedg_BV);

BVsurfF = figure;hold on
h=area(x,n_BV/sum(n_BV),'facecolor',[1 0 0]);  %%red area where the problem gonna be

legend('SCAMP')
xlabel('$$ N~[1/s]$$','Interpreter','latex','fontsize',18)
set(gca,'fontsize',14,'ygrid','on')
alpha(.5)  %%translucency of the red area

%%add new data
addLineToFig('KEPflu', [0 0 1], BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);

addLineToFig('KEPflu2', [0 1 1], BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);

addLineToFig('GASflu', [0 0 0], BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);

addLineToFig('GASflu2', [1 0 1 ], BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);

addLineToFig('EPSmin', [1 1 0], BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);

addLineToFig('GASmin', [.5 .5 0], BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);

addLineToFig('canuto', [.5 .5 .5]', BVsurfF, 'BVsurf_Num_ens', logedg_BV);
```

the subroutine `addLineToFig` consists in:

```
function addLineToFig(name, ccol, fighandle, variab, x)%, flippo, depthi)

cd(['E:\SIMULATIONS\',name,'\COMPARED\ensamble']);
load([name,'_ensamble'], variab);


[n_BVn, xout_BVn] = histc(histazza(log10(sqrt(-BVsurf_Num_ens))), x); %%new data

figure(fighandle)

[LEGHbv,OBJHbv,OUTHbv,OUTMbv] = legend; 
P=plot(x,n_BVn/sum(n_BVn),'color',ccol,'linewidth',2); %%plot new data
legend([OUTHbv;P],OUTMbv{:},name) %%update legend

end
```

Basically, I create a plot of the red area and then add data with `addLineToFig` and correctly obtain:

[image]

The problem arises when I try to duplicate the figure:

```
h1=gcf;
h2=figure;  
objects=allchild(h1);
copyobj(get(h1,'children'),h2);
set(gca,'yscale','log')
```

[image]

As you can see the translucency of the red distribution is not duplicated and the legend has some problems.

The problem appears to be the last line where I set the yscale to log. If I comment it the code works fine. Does anyone know a workaround?

**Minimal code**

```
i=linspace(0,5,100);
edges_eps=10.^(-i); 
logedg_BV= log10(fliplr(edges_eps)); 

a = 1e-5;
b = 1e-2;
r = (b-a).*rand(1000,1) + a;


[n_BV,xout_BV] = histc(histazza(log10(r)), logedg_BV);

x = logedg_BV;

%model data
r2 = (b-a).*rand(1000,1) + a;
[n_BVn,xout_BVn] = histc(histazza(log10(r2)), logedg_BV);

BVsurfF = figure;hold on
h=area(x,n_BV/sum(n_BV),'facecolor',[1 0 0]);  %%red area where the problem gonna be

legend('SCAMP')
xlabel('$$ N~[1/s]$$','Interpreter','latex','fontsize',18)
set(gca,'fontsize',14,'ygrid','on')
alpha(.5)  %%translucency of the red area

%%add new data
r3 = (b-a).*randn(1000,1) + a;
[n_BVn,xout_BVn] = histc(histazza(log10(r3)), logedg_BV);

figure(BVsurfF) 
[LEGHbv,OBJHbv,OUTHbv,OUTMbv] = legend;
P=plot(x,n_BVn/sum(n_BVn),'color','k','linewidth',2);
legend([OUTHbv;P],OUTMbv{:},'data2')

%%add new data
r4 = (b-a).*rand(1000,1) + a;
[n_BVn,xout_BVn] = histc(histazza(log10(r4)), logedg_BV);

figure(BVsurfF) 
[LEGHbv,OBJHbv,OUTHbv,OUTMbv] = legend;
P=plot(x,n_BVn/sum(n_BVn),'color','y','linewidth',2);
legend([OUTHbv;P],OUTMbv{:},'data3')




h1=gcf;
h2=figure;  
objects=allchild(h1);
copyobj(get(h1,'children'),h2);
```

Comment: I have had some similar issues with FaceAlpha when using `area`. Try using `patch` instead, it solved my problem.

Comment: Which Matlab version are you using? Can you distill your code down to a minimal reproducible set of commands that we can just ran without having to guess the inputs?

Comment: @nirvana-msu  My bad. trying to make a  minimal reproducible set of commands I figured out that the code I posted works. The problem is when after that I execute ``set(gca,'yscale','log')

Comment: @JCKaz maybe was it like so in your case either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the renderer of the original figure to 'OpenGL':

```
set(BVsurfF,'renderer','OpenGL')
```